# How to trigger re-render in Parent Component from Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

, Using props I was able to effectively pass state upwards from my child component to its parent, but a change in the state does not cause a re-render of the page.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const AddToList = (item) => {
    setText([...text, item]);
  };
 const removeFromList = (item) => {
    const index = text.indexOf(item);
    setText(text.splice(index, 1));
  };
  const [text, setText] = React.useState(["default", "default1", "default2"]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            AddToList("hello");
          }}
        >
          Add
        </button>
      </div>
      {text.map((item) => {
        return <ChildComponent text={item} removeText={removeFromList} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const ChildComponent = ({ text, removeText }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{text}</p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          removeText(text);
        }}
      >
        Remove
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In the snippet, each time AddToList is called, a new child component is created and the page is re-rendered reflecting that. However, when i call removeFromList on the child component, nothing happens. The page stays the same, even though I thought this would reduce the number of childComponents present on the page. This is the problem I'm facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated Answer (Following Edits To Original Question)

In light of your edits, the problem is that you are mutating and passing the original array in state back into itself-- React sees that it is receiving a reference to the same object, and does not update.  Instead, spread `text` into a new duplicate array, splice the duplicate array, and pass *that* into `setText`:

```
const removeFromList = (item) => {
    const index = text.indexOf(item);
    const dupeArray = [...text];
    dupeArray.splice(index, 1);
    setText(dupeArray);
};
```

You can see this [working in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1srj867f/)

### Original Answer

The reason React has things like state hooks is that you leverage them in order to plug into and trigger the React lifecycle.  Your problem does not actually have anything to do with a child attempting to update state at a parent.  It is that while your `AddToList` function is properly leveraging React state management:

```
const AddToList = (item) => {
  setText([...text, item]);
};
```

Your `removeFromList` function does *not* use any state hooks:

```
const removeFromList = (item) => {
  const index = text.indexOf(item);
  text.splice(index, 1); // you never actually setText...
};
```

...so React has no idea that state has updated.  You should rewrite it as something like:

```
const removeFromList = (item) => {
  const index = text.indexOf(item);
  const newList = text.splice(index, 1);
  setText(newList);
};
```

(Also, for what it is worth, you are being a little loose with styles-- your `AddToList` is all caps using PascalCase while `removeFromCase` is using camelCase.  Typically in JS we reserve PascalCase for `class`es, and in React we also might leverage it for components and services; we generally would *not* use it for a method or a variable.)

Comment: My bad, I copied the wrong code snippet, I actually was setting the state like you did. It still doesn't work correctly like this.

Comment: @KarryAlams - [here is a JSFiddle with your code where it seems to be working roughly as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/86rpgo5s/1/).  Is this correct, or is it somehow failing to behave as you think it should?

Comment: I'm stupid lol, I forgot to populate the lists first, but try it now. It deletes everything and leaves the last entered item. Which isn't what it's supposed to be doing. I intended that it would delete only that one item from the list. You can try it again

Comment: At this point the amount of changes you have made make this a completely different problem than the one you originally posted, as the code has now changed two time.  Even my original answer is no longer applicable tot he question that was first posed.  I'm not really certain how to proceed here-- I'll probably just end up deleting this answer.

Comment: I apologize. but I don't think there's any more issues. Removing a specific item causes unexpected behaviour thats the problem im trying to solve. Can you take one more look?

Comment: @KarryAlams - see updated answer